# Close open files on server

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008-r2

How can I (e.g. via WMI) close all open files on a share on a server?

Comment: What do you mean by that? What are you trying to achieve by "closing" the files?

Comment: Presumably, it is a file server and someone has a word document open which prevents other people from opening that word document. (Or other similar situation)

Comment: @Colin (sry for late answer) ... my users have to run an app directly from a server share, therefor the files remains open while the users are runningn the app. When I have to update the app, I need to force the open files closed, so I can overwrite the files with new version. I can do it within "Share and storage management", but then I have to do it manually. I need to do it programtaticaly - any idea how? thx